# Constraint in Lagrangian for mass spring system.

Tags: numerical-methods, calculus-of-variations, lagrange-multiplier, classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

Suppose we have $p_1,...,p_n$ and we have springs attached to them. We know that the lagrangian is
$$
L = T - U = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{2} m_i \dot{p}_i^2 - \sum_{(i,j) \in E} \frac{1}{2} k_{ij} \left( \left\lVert p_i - p_j \right\rVert - r_{ij}\right)^2
$$

And the Euler lagrange equations are

$$
m_i \frac{d^2 p_i}{d t^2} = - \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}(i)} k_{ij}\left( \left\lVert p_i - p_j \right\rVert - r_{ij}\right) \frac{p_i - p_j}{\left\lVert p_i - p_j \right\rVert}
$$

Here $k_{ij}$ are elastic constants for the spring connecting vertex $i$ to vertex $j$, $E$ is the set of springs (modelled as pair of indices), $m_i$ is the i-th particle mass.

What I was wondering now suppose we have $p_k = p_k(t)$ for $k \in C \subset \left\{1,...,n \right\}$, so some of these particles have known trajectory (i.e. I am constraining them).

How do the Euler lagrange equation change? I've been trying to understand the how the constrained variations would apply in this case and I've been watching [this tutorial](https://youtu.be/pdO14dqC_nI?t=472) but I struggle to work out the equation.

My only guess was to model everything as

$$
\begin{array}{ll}
\min L = \min T - U & \\
s.t. \left\lVert p_k - p_k(t) \right\rVert^2 = 0 & \text{for $k \in C$}
\end{array}
$$

where $p_k(t)$ are given functions. I know in standard optimization we can use lagrange multipliers and it seems like according to the tutorial I shared we can extend the use to calculus of variations, I don't know why however I get confused when it comes to plug everything together.

Can anyone please clarify how to correctly include constraints in my case?

**Update** : This is what I have so far.. I am referring to [Calculus of variations of Gelfand](http://users.uoa.gr/%7Epjioannou/mech2/READING/Gelfand_Fomin_Calculus_of_Variations.pdf) (Specifically theorem 2 of chapter 2, in section 12.2)

I rewrite my constraints as equivalent

$$
G(p_{k_1},\ldots,p_{k_N}) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k \in C} \left\lVert p_k - \hat{p}_k \right\rVert^2
$$

Where $\hat{p}$ are given functions. Using the theory of lagrange multipliers in this case I believe yields

$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial q_i} + \lambda \frac{\partial G}{\partial q_i} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}_i} = 0
$$

Where given the type of constraint $\lambda$ is in general a function of $t$.

I have two cases to consider when deriving the system of differential equations if $i \notin C$ then we have
$$
m_i \frac{d^2 p_i}{d t^2} = - \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}(i)} k_{ij}\left( \left\lVert p_i - p_j \right\rVert - r_{ij}\right) \frac{p_i - p_j}{\left\lVert p_i - p_j \right\rVert} \;\;\;\;\; (1)
$$

If $i \in C$ instead we have

$$
m_i \frac{d^2 p_i}{d t^2} = - \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}(i)} k_{ij}\left( \left\lVert p_i - p_j \right\rVert - r_{ij}\right) \frac{p_i - p_j}{\left\lVert p_i - p_j \right\rVert} - \lambda (p_i - \hat{p_i})
$$

Because of my constraint $G$ however we have $p_i = \hat{p}_i$ so in truth we have

$$
\frac{d^2 \hat{p}_i}{d t^2} = - \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}(i)} k_{ij}\left( \left\lVert \hat{p}_i - p_j \right\rVert - r_{ij}\right) \frac{\hat{p}_i - p_j}{\left\lVert \hat{p}_i - p_j \right\rVert} \;\;\;\;\; (2)
$$

Now despite (2) and (1) might look the same what we have is a system of equation on $\left\{q_i\right\}$ however part of them are differential equations and part of them are algebraic equations (because if $i \in C$ then $\hat{p}_i$ is known). What I am looking for is for some numerical method that would enable me to solve the system of equations (differential + algebraic). I know methods for solving separately differential equations and algebraic equations, but I don't know if I wanted to combine them what I need to do.

Another alternative could be simplifying even further the system but then I don't really know how to do it.

Here I am now stuck because I don't know how to deal with this kind of systems. If anyone has a suggestion it would great.

Comment: The focused case study is trivially solved by considering the $\hat{p}_i$ instead $p_i$ so reducing the system degree to $N-C$. A more interesting question would be to consider constraints like $\|p_i-\hat{p}_i\| = c_i\gt 0$.

Comment: Yes, but this yields to constraint on the neighbour particles

Answer (score 2):

Considering non trivial constraints of type $\|p_i-\hat{p}_i\|=c_i\gt 0$, which are holonomomic, those constraints can be integrated into the Lagrangian as follows:

$$
L = T-U + \sum_{j\in C}\lambda_j(\|p_j-\hat{p}_j\|-c_j)
$$

so the movement equations are obtained from

$$
\cases{
m_i \frac{d^2 p_i}{d t^2} + \sum_{j \in \mathcal{N}(i)} k_{ij}\left( \left\lVert p_i - p_j \right\rVert - r_{ij}\right) \frac{p_i - p_j}{\left\lVert p_i - p_j \right\rVert}+\lambda_i\frac{p_i - \hat{p}_i}{\left\lVert p_i - \hat{p}_i \right\rVert}=0\\
\|p_j-\hat{p}_j\|-c_j=0
}
$$

so we have $\lambda_j,\ \ j\in C$ additional unknowns and $\|p_j-\hat{p}_j\|-c_j=0,\ \ j\in C$ additional equations.

NOTE

To avoid the solution of a system of differential-algebraic equations, we can consider instead $\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(\|p_j-\hat{p}_j\|-c_j\right)=0$ and then we can obtain a set of ordinary differential equations for $\frac{d^2p_i}{dt^2},\ \ i\in N$, which are $\lambda_j$ independent, being aware that the initial conditions for this ODE system should be consistent with the constraints.

Attached a MATHEMATICA script modeling the reduced case study with three points in the plane, with one of then constrained by $\|p_1-\hat{p}_1\|= c_1$ where $\hat{p}_1$ describes a centered circle with radius $r$ and angular velocity $\omega$

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Norma[x_] := Sqrt[x.x]
Subscript[p, 1][t_] := {Subscript[x, 1][t], Subscript[y, 1][t]};
Subscript[p, 2][t_] := {Subscript[x, 2][t], Subscript[y, 2][t]};
Subscript[p, 3][t_] := {Subscript[x, 3][t], Subscript[y, 3][t]};
Subscript[q, 1][t_] := {Subscript[f, 1][t], Subscript[g, 1][t]};
Ek = 1/2 Sum[Subscript[m, i]D[Subscript[p, i][t], t].D[Subscript[p, i][t], t], {i, 1, 3}];
Ep = 1/2 (Subscript[k, 1, 2] (Norma[Subscript[p, 1][t] - Subscript[p, 2][t]] - Subscript[r, 1, 2]) + Subscript[k, 2, 
  3] (Norma[Subscript[p, 2][t] - Subscript[p, 3][t]] - Subscript[r, 2, 3]) + Subscript[k, 1, 3] (Norma[Subscript[p, 1][t] - Subscript[p, 3][t]] - Subscript[r, 1, 3]));
L = Ek - Ep + Subscript[lambda, 1] (Norma[Subscript[p, 1][t] - Subscript[q, 1][t]] - Subscript[c, 1]);
vars = Flatten[{Subscript[p, 1][t], Subscript[p, 2][t], Subscript[p, 3][t]}];
dvars = D[vars, t];
equsmov = D[Grad[L, dvars], t] - Grad[L, vars];
equsmovtot = Join[equsmov, {D[Norma[Subscript[p, 1][t] - Subscript[q, 1][t]] - Subscript[c, 1],t, t]}];
solsacc = Solve[Thread[equsmovtot == 0], Join[D[dvars, t], {Subscript[lambda, 1]}]][[1]];
parms = {Subscript[m, 1] -> 1, Subscript[m, 2] -> 1, Subscript[m, 3] -> 1, Subscript[k, 1, 2] -> 10, Subscript[k, 2, 3] -> 10, Subscript[k, 1, 3] -> 10, Subscript[r, 1, 2] -> 5, Subscript[r, 2, 3] -> 5, Subscript[r, 1, 3] -> 5, Subscript[c, 1] -> 3};
omega = 1;
r = 10;
Subscript[f, 1][t_] := r Cos[omega t]
Subscript[g, 1][t_] := r Sin[omega t]
solsacc0 = solsacc /. parms;
ODES = Thread[D[dvars, t] == (D[dvars, t] /. solsacc0)];
cinits = Join[Thread[(vars /. {t -> 0}) == {r - Subscript[c, 1], 0, 0, 10, 0, -10} /. parms], Thread[(dvars /. {t -> 0}) == 0]];
tmax = 7 ;
dt = 0.1;
solp = NDSolve[Join[ODES, cinits], vars, {t, 0, tmax}][[1]]
p1 = Table[Evaluate[Subscript[p, 1][t] /. solp], {t, 0, tmax, dt}];
p2 = Table[Evaluate[Subscript[p, 2][t] /. solp], {t, 0, tmax, dt}];
p3 = Table[Evaluate[Subscript[p, 3][t] /. solp], {t, 0, tmax, dt}];
gr12 = Table[ParametricPlot[p1[[k]] t + p2[[k]] (1 - t), {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Red], {k, 1, Length[p1]}];
gr23 = Table[ParametricPlot[p2[[k]] t + p3[[k]] (1 - t), {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Blue], {k, 1, Length[p1]}];
gr13 = Table[ParametricPlot[p1[[k]] t + p3[[k]] (1 - t), {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Green], {k, 1, Length[p1]}];
gr0 = ParametricPlot[{Subscript[f, 1][t], Subscript[g, 1][t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi/omega}];
pc = Table[{Subscript[f, 1][t], Subscript[g, 1][t]}, {t, 0, tmax, dt}];
grc = Table[ParametricPlot[pc[[k]] t + p1[[k]] (1 - t), {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> Black], {k, 1, Length[p1]}];
gr1 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Subscript[p, 1][t] /. solp], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}];
gr2 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Subscript[p, 2][t] /. solp], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}];
gr3 = ParametricPlot[Evaluate[Subscript[p, 3][t] /. solp], {t, 0, tmax}, PlotStyle -> {Dashed, Black}];
Show[gr1, gr2, gr3, gr12, gr23, gr13, gr0, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
Show[gr0, grc, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
ListPlot[Table[{(k - 1) dt, Norm[pc[[k]] - p1[[k]]]}, {k, 1, Length[p1]}]]
```

Follows a plot showing in red blue and green respectively, the springs $(p_1,p_2)$, $(p_2,p_3)$ and $(p_1,p_3)$.

[image]

Follows also another plot showing the preservation of distance $c_1$ between $p_1$ and $q_1$ representing $\hat{p}_1$.

[image]